# vim trick to align blocks/end keywords in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, vim, macvim

Is there a way to simply have my blocks and their closing end keyword align properly with vim? If I have a function which is nested with several conditions, things can start to get ugly fast. Can vim save the day?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sure. Just select the relevant block of code and press <kbd>=</kbd>.

Comment: +1: I've been using Vim for about 6 years, and I never knew this.

Comment: Actually, this is *just* what I needed. Awesome, thanks Peter.

Comment: All this seems to do for me is move everything selected to the same column.  What am I missing?

Comment: @.yahoo-co-jpaqwsykcj3aulh3h1: you should `:set ft=ruby` first. This means you won't have ruby indenting support turned on.

Comment: Thanks Peter.  The filetype was correct but it looks like I was missing "filetype plugin indent on" in the config file.

Answer (score 3):

There's also a nice Vim plugin called [endwise](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2386) that automatically inserts the ends for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
gg=G
```

(go to top, re-indent all the way down to the bottom)